# Reliably selecting an annotion in MKMapView on start (in both ios 6 and ios 5.1)?

Tags: ios, ios5, mkmapview, ios6

From a detail view of an event I want to go to a MapViewController, zoom in to the annotation, and open it's callout.
Here is some of the relevant code:

```
@interface MapViewController : UIViewController<MKMapViewDelegate>
...
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
  [self displayAnnotations];
}

- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    ...
    // Zoom in to event
    [map setRegion:region animated:YES];        
}

- (void) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
   ...
   regionAnimationEnded = YES;
   [self selectAnnotation:a];
   ...
}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views
{
   ...
   // check to see if the right view is in the array
   ...
   annotationViewDidAppear = YES;
   [self selectAnnotation:a];
   ...   
}

- (void) selectAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
   if(annotationViewDidAppear && regionAnimationEnded)
   {
     if(!openedAnnotationFirstTime)
     {
        [map selectAnnotation:annotation animated:YES];
        openedAnnotationFirstTime = YES;
     }
   }
}
```

This works on the ios 6 simulator, but on the ios 5.1 simulator (and on the device) the annotion view isn't visible as it says in the docs:

> (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views 
>       By the time this method is called, the specified views are already added to the map.

So it depends which finishes first: if the region change animation finishes last and the annotation view has appeared it works, otherwise it doesn't.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using perform selector with delay on the actual [map selectAnnotation:annotation animated:YES]; 
It's a work-around but seems to work nicely.

Comment: Sometimes it is, but the issue is that it depends on the performance of the device, so can still fail.

Answer (score 0):

Your `selectAnnotation:` method is being called twice. Try calling it only once, in `mapView:regionDidChangeAnimated:` delegate method.

Comment: the actual [map selectAnnotation: animated:] is only called once, after both flags are set to YES

Comment: Your class' own selectAnnotation: method appears to be called in both MKMapViewDelegate methods. Probably best to keep it in the mapView:regionDidChangeAnimated: delegate method only, as that should be called last according to your code.